# Webstorm выбрасывает ошибку Angular когда прописываю пайп

Tags: angular

```
Unresolved pipe date
<p>{{new | date}}</p>




import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {PostComponent} from "./post/post.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PostComponent
  ],
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }





Ошибка происходит не только при пайпах , но и при [ngClass] [(ngModel)] 

Данную ошибку начинает выкидывать первого запуска приложения через npm start или ng serve , до 
этого все ок
```

Comment: Unresolved pipe date - ошибка

Comment: Приложение работает нормально , но меня это сбивает с толку

Comment: + еще раз повторю - Данную ошибку начинает выкидывать первого запуска приложения через npm start или ng serve , до 
этого - все ок

Comment: замените название переменной new, это же зарезервированное слово

Comment: New - опечатка . Там now